# Magit throws error when I press "h" or "c"

Tags: magit

I have installed Emacs on a fresh install of Elementary OS, and I have just installed Magit. When I run `magit-status` in a repository, and press either  the `c` or `h` key, magit throws an error. The error starts with `cl-etypecase failed:`, but I do not understand what is wrong, or how I can fix it.

Does anyone know why this fails?

The error message is pasted below. My magit version is `Magit 20190214.2056, Git 2.17.1, Emacs 25.2.1, gnu/linux`.

```
cl-etypecase failed: [eieio-class-tag--transient-columns 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ([eieio-class-tag--transient-column 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ([eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil A magit-cherry-pick unbound  %k %d Apply] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil b magit-branch unbound  %k %d Branch] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil B magit-bisect unbound  %k %d Bisect] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil c magit-commit unbound  %k %d Commit] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil d magit-diff unbound  %k %d Diff] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil D magit-diff-refresh unbound  %k %d Diff (change)] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil e magit-ediff-dwim unbound  %k %d Ediff (dwim)] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil E magit-ediff unbound  %k %d Ediff]) nil nil] [eieio-class-tag--transient-column 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ([eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil f magit-fetch unbound  %k %d Fetch] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil F magit-pull unbound  %k %d Pull] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil l magit-log unbound  %k %d Log] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil L magit-log-refresh unbound  %k %d Log (change)] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil m magit-merge unbound  %k %d Merge] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil M magit-remote unbound  %k %d Remote] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil o magit-submodule unbound  %k %d Submodule] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil O magit-subtree unbound  %k %d Subtree]) nil nil] [eieio-class-tag--transient-column 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ([eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil P magit-push unbound  %k %d Push] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil r magit-rebase unbound  %k %d Rebase] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil t magit-tag unbound  %k %d Tag] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil T magit-notes unbound  %k %d Note] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil V magit-revert unbound  %k %d Revert] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil w magit-am unbound  %k %d Apply patches] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil W magit-patch unbound  %k %d Format patches] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil X magit-reset unbound  %k %d Reset]) nil nil] [eieio-class-tag--transient-column 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ([eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil y magit-show-refs unbound  %k %d Show Refs] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil z magit-stash unbound  %k %d Stash] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil ! magit-run unbound  %k %d Run] [eieio-class-tag--transient-suffix 1 nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil % magit-worktree unbound  %k %d Worktree]) nil nil]) nil Transient and dwim commands], (integer string list transient-group transient-suffix
```

Comment: Did the new `transient` dependency get installed? Did you try restarting Emacs?

Comment: Also see https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3732.

Comment: Thanks. The transient dependency is installed, and restarting did not help. Neither did uninstall magit, restart, install magit, as suggested in the github issue.

Comment: This should never happen.
1. Could you post your init.el it should be in ~/.emacs.d folder.
2. post M-x emacs-version output.
3. Did you update/upgrade your OS packages after fresh install (apt-get update/upgrade)

Comment: Must be a local issue or it would get reported more often.

Comment: This was resolved in https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/3732.